# Removing Hardcoding of XML elements from Struts action class

Tags: struts2, velocity

In my application I am using struts 2. we are sending an AJAX call using jQuery. I am formatting the XML data in Struts 2 action class and sending that as XML response to to AJAX request. I am formatting the XML data in struts actions similar to this:

```
<person>
  <age>

  </age>

  <city>

  </city>
</person>
```

What I am looking for is moving this XML data to a separate XML file. Someone told me that we can use Velocity to create XML dynamically. Can someone please help me? A sample code would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I added the velocity tag since you specifically mentioned that technology, but there are a number of options available to you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of options available to you. First, you can use JSP to output XML. To do so, just start the JSP off as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<%@ page contentType="text/xml;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
```

Additionally, you can also use a templating language such as Velocity or Freemarker.

Lastly, for a bit of a different approach, you can use the XML Streaming API (`javax.xml.stream` package), which lets you programatically build XML.

If you are already using JSP for your view layer, then using JSP for your XML output may be the easiest approach. Otherwise, I'd recommend that you look at the streaming API. Velocity and Freemarker are both good templating languages, but I wouldn't personally use them just for producing XML, especially if you're using something else to generate your HTML.

Comment: I have read the xml data back in my ajax callback function, so if I want to avoid putting hardcoded xml data in my action class, where else can I put it and then how can I read it in my ajax call back function? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick snapshot how to init and use Velocity with Tools:

```
//init velocity
VelocityEngine velocity = new VelocityEngine();
velocity.setProperty(VelocityEngine.FILE_RESOURCE_LOADER_PATH, "/path/to/templates/dir/");
velocity.setProperty(VelocityEngine.FILE_RESOURCE_LOADER_CACHE, true);
velocity.init();

//init tools
ToolManager velocityToolManager = new ToolManager();
velocityToolManager.configure("velocity-tools.xml");

//get template
Template template = velocity.getTemplate("demo.vm"); //contains ${msg}

//create context
VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext(velocityToolManager.createContext());

//pass data do context
context.put("msg", "Hello from Velocity");

//process template
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
template.merge(context, sw);

//parsed template as a string
String parsedTemplate = sw.toString();
```